# Symfony2 translation load company wise but more 100 company create got Error: Allowed memory size

Tags: symfony

In my project I need to use load translation company wise seprate, So I have create a Translator class and it's work find when 100 company created but then I got "FatalErrorException:  Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" error. My class are followed

```
----- Added this code in service file ------
#<your project name>/src/Raghuvir/UserBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    translate:
        class: Raghuvir\UserBundle\Translation\RaghuvirTranslator
        arguments: ["@service_container", "@logger"]
```

Translator class

```
<?php
namespace Raghuvir\UserBundle\Translation;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;

class RaghuvirTranslator extends Translator 
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $snCompanyId = $this->container->get('session')->get('id_clinic');

        if (null === $locale) {
            $locale = $this->getLocale();
        }

        if ($snCompanyId == "") {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }else{
            $domain = $snCompanyId.'_messages';
        }

        $referef = $this->container->get('request')->server->get('REQUEST_URI');

        if( preg_match('/super/', $referef) ) {
            $domain = 'messages';
        } else if( preg_match('/admin/', $referef) ) {
            $adminLangFilePath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../src/RaghuvirClinicAdmin/DefaultBundle/Resources/translations/'.$domain;
            if( $this->container->getParameter('admin_translation') == 0 || !file_exists($adminLangFilePath.'.'.$locale.'.yml') ) {
                $domain = 'messages';
            }
        } else if( preg_match('/api/', $referef) || preg_match('/rest/', $referef) ) {
            $apiLangFilePath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../src/RaghuvirApi/ApiBundle/Resources/translations/'.$domain;
            if( $this->container->getParameter('api_translation') == 0 || !file_exists($apiLangFilePath.'.'.$locale.'.yml') ) {
                $domain = 'messages';
            }
        } else {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }

        if (!isset($this->catalogues[$locale])) {
            $this->loadCatalogue($locale);
        }

        // Change translation domain to 'messages' if a translation can't be found in the
        // current domain
        if ('messages' !== $domain && false === $this->catalogues[$locale]->has((string) $id, $domain)) {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }

        return strtr($this->catalogues[$locale]->get((string) $id, $domain), $parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will get error "FatalErrorException:  Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted" because in you have company wise translation files. So when you call translator in twig/controller/service all files contain merge and create cache files. File location "app/cache/dev/translations/*'. After the create cache files you call translator it will load from cache file and file have heavy load data that's why you will get error

Solution are follow: 
- Before you use follow code check translation cache folder you will get language wise files like "catalogue.fi.php and catalogue.fi.php.meta"
- After use following code it will create company id wise separately like "6_catalogue.fi.php and 6_catalogue.fi.php.meta"
Just use the following class

```
<?php
namespace Raghuvir\UserBundle\Translation;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Translation\Translator;
use Symfony\Component\Config\ConfigCache;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\LoaderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue;

class RaghuvirTranslator extends Translator 
{
    /**
     * @var LoaderInterface[]
     */
    private $loaders = array();

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $resources = array();


    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function trans($id, array $parameters = array(), $domain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        $snCompanyId = $this->container->get('session')->get('id_clinic');

        if (null === $locale) {
            $locale = $this->getLocale();
        }

        if ($snCompanyId == "") {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }else{
            $domain = $snCompanyId.'_messages';
        }

        $referef = $this->container->get('request')->server->get('REQUEST_URI');

        if( preg_match('/super/', $referef) ) {
            $domain = 'messages';
        } else if( preg_match('/admin/', $referef) ) {
            $adminLangFilePath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../src/RaghuvirClinicAdmin/DefaultBundle/Resources/translations/'.$domain;
            if( $this->container->getParameter('admin_translation') == 0 || !file_exists($adminLangFilePath.'.'.$locale.'.yml') ) {
                $domain = 'messages';
            }
        } else if( preg_match('/api/', $referef) || preg_match('/rest/', $referef) ) {
            $apiLangFilePath = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../src/RaghuvirApi/ApiBundle/Resources/translations/'.$domain;
            if( $this->container->getParameter('api_translation') == 0 || !file_exists($apiLangFilePath.'.'.$locale.'.yml') ) {
                $domain = 'messages';
            }
        } else {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }

        if (!isset($this->catalogues[$locale])) {
            $this->loadCatalogue($locale);
        }

        // Change translation domain to 'messages' if a translation can't be found in the
        // current domain
        if ('messages' !== $domain && false === $this->catalogues[$locale]->has((string) $id, $domain)) {
            $domain = 'messages';
        }

        return strtr($this->catalogues[$locale]->get((string) $id, $domain), $parameters);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function loadCatalogue($locale)
    {
        if (isset($this->catalogues[$locale])) {
            return;
        }

        if (null === $this->options['cache_dir']) {
            $this->initialize();

            return $this->customeLoadCatalogue($locale);
            //return parent::loadCatalogue($locale);
        }

        $snCompanyId = $this->container->get('session')->get('id_clinic');

        $domain = ($snCompanyId != "")? $snCompanyId.'_' : '';

        $cache = new ConfigCache($this->options['cache_dir'].'/'.$domain.'catalogue.'.$locale.'.php', $this->options['debug']);

        if (!$cache->isFresh()) {

            $this->initialize();

            //parent::loadCatalogue($locale);
            $this->customeLoadCatalogue($locale);

            $fallbackContent = '';
            $current = '';
            foreach ($this->computeFallbackLocales($locale) as $fallback) {
                $fallbackContent .= sprintf(<<<EOF
\$catalogue%s = new MessageCatalogue('%s', %s);
\$catalogue%s->addFallbackCatalogue(\$catalogue%s);


EOF
                    ,
                    ucfirst($fallback),
                    $fallback,
                    var_export($this->catalogues[$fallback]->all(), true),
                    ucfirst($current),
                    ucfirst($fallback)
                );
                $current = $fallback;
            }

            $content = sprintf(<<<EOF
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue;

\$catalogue = new MessageCatalogue('%s', %s);

%s
return \$catalogue;

EOF
                ,
                $locale,
                var_export($this->catalogues[$locale]->all(), true),
                $fallbackContent
            );

            $cache->write($content, $this->catalogues[$locale]->getResources());

            return;
        }

        $this->catalogues[$locale] = include $cache;
    }


    protected function customeLoadCatalogue($locale)
    {
        $this->doLoadCatalogue($locale);
        $this->loadFallbackCatalogues($locale);
    }


    private function doLoadCatalogue($locale)
    {
        $this->catalogues[$locale] = new MessageCatalogue($locale);

        $snCompanyId = $this->container->get('session')->get('id_clinic');
        $domain = ($snCompanyId != "")? $snCompanyId.'_' : '';

        if (isset($this->resources[$locale])) {
            foreach ($this->resources[$locale] as $resource) {
                if (!isset($this->loaders[$resource[0]])) {
                    throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('The "%s" translation loader is not registered.', $resource[0]));
                }
                if($resource[2] == 'validators' || $resource[2] == 'messages' ||
                   $resource[2] == $domain.'validators' || $resource[2] == $domain.'messages') {
                        $this->catalogues[$locale]->addCatalogue($this->loaders[$resource[0]]->load($resource[1], $locale, $resource[2]));
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public function addLoader($format, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $this->loaders[$format] = $loader;
    }

    public function addResource($format, $resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages')
    {

        $this->resources[$locale][] = array($format, $resource, $domain);

      //  unset($this->catalogues[$locale]);
    }

    private function loadFallbackCatalogues($locale)
    {
        $current = $this->catalogues[$locale];

        foreach ($this->computeFallbackLocales($locale) as $fallback) {
            if (!isset($this->catalogues[$fallback])) {
                $this->doLoadCatalogue($fallback);
            }

            $current->addFallbackCatalogue($this->catalogues[$fallback]);
            $current = $this->catalogues[$fallback];
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you will get solution of your issue...